# Fullcalendar.io + React: locale/is doesn't translate monthnames

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, localization, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar v5 with react.
I am using it with icelandic language but it won't translate all of the words when using the Chrome browser. Works on Firefox.

This is my import: *import allLocales from "@fullcalendar/core/locales-all";*

I was able to customize weekday names like so:

```
const dayNamesIs = ['sunnudagur', 'mánudagur', 'þriðjudagur', 'miðvikudagur', 'fimmtudagur', 'föstudagur', 'laugardagur'];
    const dayNamesShortIs = ['sun', 'mán', 'þri', 'mið', 'fim', 'fös', 'lau'];
...
<FullCalendar
   ref={calendarRef}
   plugins={[momentPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
   initialView="dayGridMonth"
   selectable={true}
   editable={true}
   firstDay={1}
   locales={allLocales}
   locale="is"
   titleFormat={'MMMM YYYY'}
   monthMode
   dayHeaderFormat={{weekday: 'long'}}
   slotLabelFormat={{
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: false,
        hour12: false,
      }}
   nowIndicator={true}
   dayHeaderContent={function (arg) {
        if (document.body.clientWidth < 1000) {
            return dayNamesShortIs[arg.date.getDay()]
        }
        return dayNamesIs[arg.date.getDay()]
    }}
    dayMaxEventRows={true}
```

but I've spent a lot of time trying to find a way to customize the month names in the title without any solution.

I checked [the demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale-demo) for locales in fullcalendar.io - and it just doesn't translate all to Icelandic (when using chrome) :( I know we are a small nation but common.. ;)

I know this is not a fullcalendar problem and I am also trying to use some polyfill(without much luck yet) to help the browser translate...

Hope somebody can help, thanks :)

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: P.S. You're correct, fullCalendar just uses the month names provided by your browser's date/time library, and its internationalisation settings. This can vary depending on the browser vendor. If you want help with your polyfull attempt please update the question with a [mre] of the issue including code as text rather than pictures, as I mentioned above. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of how i set the formatting in titleFormat.
It caused the polyfill to not work as it should have. Bear in mind that a polyfill is still needed for many languages.

was:

```
<FullCalendar
   ref={calendarRef}
   plugins={[momentPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
   initialView="dayGridMonth"
   selectable={true}
   editable={true}
   firstDay={1}
   locales={allLocales}
   locale="is"
   titleFormat={'MMMM YYYY'}
   monthMode
```

but should be:

```
<FullCalendar
   ref={calendarRef}
   plugins={[momentPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
   initialView="dayGridMonth"
   selectable={true}
   editable={true}
   firstDay={1}
   locales={allLocales}
   locale="is"
   titleFormat={
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long'
   }
   monthMode
```

these are the imports that I am using for the polyfill:

```
import '@formatjs/intl-numberformat/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/is' // locale-data for en
import '@formatjs/intl-displaynames/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/is' // locale-data for icelandic
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill-force' // Using force to use our polyfill
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/is' // Add locales you want
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/is'
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/add-all-tz' // Add ALL tz data
import '@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-locale/polyfill';
```

see [here](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-datetimeformat)